# selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression is invalid using By.XPATH through Selenium Python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, python-3.10, selenium4, invalidselectorexception

I'm trying to develop an autologin für Instagram and I got the following problem.

Here is my code:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
sleep(2)
login_link = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[text()=´Allow essential and optional cookies`]")
```

Here is the Error Message:

> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\justu\PycharmProject\botinsta\main.py", line 18, in 
> > login_link = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[text()=´Allow essential and optional cookies`]")   File "C:\Users\justu\PycharmProject\botinsta\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 857, in find_element return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {   File "C:\Users\justu\PycharmProject\botinsta\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 435, in execute self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\justu\PycharmProject\botinsta\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression "//button[text()=´Allow essential and optional cookies`]" is invalid: SyntaxError: Document.evaluate: The expression
> > is not a legal expression Stacktrace:
> > WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:188:5
> > InvalidSelectorError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:348:5
> > find_@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:320:11
> > element.find/</findElements<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:274:24
> > evalFn@chrome://remote/content/marionette/sync.js:136:7
> > PollPromise/<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/sync.js:156:5
> > PollPromise@chrome://remote/content/marionette/sync.js:127:10
> > element.find/<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:272:24
> > element.find@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:271:10
> > findElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.jsm:245:25
> > receiveMessage@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.jsm:101:31

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

Try single quotes

```
'Allow essential and optional cookies'
```

instead of

```
´Allow essential and optional cookies`
```

P.S. Since you use `browser.implicitly_wait(5)` there is no need in `time.sleep(2)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of a couple of things.

- If you are passing the *xpath* within double quotes i.e. `"..."` then you need to provide the value of the attribues within single quotes i.e. `'...'`
- `<button>` element is a ***clickable*** element. So you need to identify when the element is ***interactable***.

---

### Solution

Incorporating the above mentioned points and removing the `sleep(2)`, your effective lines of code will be:

```
browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
login_link = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Allow essential and optional cookies']")))
```

- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```